# Select special HTML file for print

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, media-queries

Is it possible to select special HTML file just for print purposes?

I have a [webpage](http://eaccepta.cz/test/) which loads its content dynamically into one div, but for printing purposes I need to see whole content (every picture). So I created a code snippet just for print which is normally invisible and gets visible only when user print the page - I used @media print.

But this solution has negative impact on webpage loading speed. So I was wondering, could I  manage to print standalone HTML file? I want to seperate the HTML snippet into standalone HTML file and load it only when needed (when user prints). Maybe using javascript?

I hope I explained it clearly :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use a separate *stylesheet* to change the markup of the page for printing. You can't however have a automatically separate HTML file for it. Easiest way, imho, is to put a link on your page to a print page.

Comment: Try the following link,it will be helpful for your query : http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3471121/Print-a-Web-Page-Using-JavaScript.htm

Comment: the easiest way is to add a button called *print*, link it to the print-version file, and call `window.print()` after that file is loaded.

Comment: @rhgb Thanks! That sounds like solution for my problem :)